# Error while converting string to decimal

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a mi BD mediante este procedimiento almacenado, consta de dos filtros de tipo `decimal` y uno de tipo de `int` para determinar que tipo de consulta quiero realizar, bien, el error que me arroja es que esta fallando al convertir el tipo `string` a tipo `decimal`, pero estoy haciendo la conversión, no entiendo porque me arroja el error.

```
   using (SqlConnection cn = Claseconexion.ObtenerConexion())
            {


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_FILTROSLISTADOINGRESOS", cn);
                adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ACCION", SqlDbType.Int);
                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ACCION"].Value = 4;

                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MONTO1", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@MONTO1"].Value = decimal.Parse(txtmonto1.Text);

                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MONTO2", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@MONTO2"].Value = decimal.Parse(txtmonto2.Text);

                adaptador.Fill(dt);

                dtgvlistadoDeIngresos.DataSource = dt;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta utilizando la función Convert.ToDecimal

ejemplo:

```
adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@MONTO2"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtmonto2.Text);
```

Comment: lo intente y me arroja el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la respuesta intentando con distintas formas y la solución a la que llegué fue:

Designar variables del tipo de dato que estoy manejando (DECIMAL en este caso):

```
decimal monto1=0;

decimal monto2=0;
```

Luego le asigné de donde tomarían el valor:

```
decimal.TryParse(txtmonto1.Text, out monto1);

decimal.TryParse(txtmonto2.Text, out monto2);
```

Finalmente en el procedimiento almacenado pasé la variable directamente:

```
adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MONTO1", SqlDbType.Decimal);
adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@MONTO1"].Value = monto1;

adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@MONTO2", SqlDbType.Decimal);
adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters["@MONTO2"].Value = monto2;
```